# create my own active directory in a EC2 instance of Windows 2012 in AWS?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, amazon-web-services

I have been using Azure where I could use one of the Windows VM as a domain server with AD sitting in subnet 1 while others VMs sit on the subnet 2. So far so good.

Now I am building the similar VMs, and apparently I could use AWS provided AD services and create a small Simple Directory which charges $36 a month. I am not sure if I missed something. Can I create my own active directory in a EC2 instance of Windows 2012 without using AWS AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I create my own active directory in a EC2 instance of Windows 2012
>   without using AWS AD?

Sure - why couldn't you? It's a windows server, and you're free to do whatever you like with it. Like any AD deployment, you should have at least two DCs, and you'll need to sort out how to get your clients secure access to the server.

Comment: Yes, I would had thought so since I had done this in Azure no drama. In AWS, the other VMs could not see the domain server I nominated with AD, unless I use Simple AD. The docs in AWS seemly all point to Simple AD. Any other resource to create my own LAN in AWS so my domain applications could run?? I don't need to connect to on-premise domain.

Comment: You need to be running on a VPC. After that, everything should fall in place nicely. Keep security groups and network ACLs in mind. If you have further questions after trying to get it set up, just ask another question here and we'll help you out.

Comment: I have read the PDF, briefly. Apparently I have better to setup 2 VMs just for the AD and domain. It might be better just use Simple AD which will take care of all domain lookup.

Answer (score 0):

As EEAA suggested, it's just a Windows VM and yes you can. There are, however, some best practices you might want to understand. Here is guidance from AWS on their recommended reference architecture:

http://aws.amazon.com/windows/resources/whitepapers/ad/